# jquery toggle, adding image to close

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am new to jQuery and have created a tab, which slides out when clicked. I would like to add an image to let the user know the tab can be clicked to hide it.

I currently have this jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/KcF4u/1/

My current code is

```
$('.box, aside h2').delay(2000);
$('.box').animate({ right:"-12"});
$('aside h2').animate({ right:"270"});
    $("aside h2").toggle(function(){
    $('.box').animate({ right:"-335"});
    $('aside h2').animate({ right:"-55"});
    },function(){
        $('.box').animate({ right:"-12"});
        $('aside h2').animate({ right:"270"});
    });
```

I have included an image of the cross, but would only like the image visible when the tab is fully expanded.

Any ideas how this can be done?

I also feel my current code is a bit bloated, I would be very grateful if you can let me know how to simplify this also.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In order to simplify your code, could you maybe provide a list of steps the animation should take? It might be because of the time of night, but I can't parse that animation in my head...sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this seems to work. Not my best effort, but you know. **EDIT**: That's a lot better.

**CSS**

```
#news img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: -65px;
    display: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var $aside = $('#news'),
    $box = $aside.find('.box'),
    $h2 = $aside.find('h2'),
    $img = $box.find('img');

$aside.on('click', 'h2, .box img', toggle);

$h2.data('toggleout', false);

setTimeout(toggle, 2000);

function toggle() {
    var pos = [-12, 270],
        active = true;

    if ($h2.data('toggleout')) {
        pos = [-355, -55];

        $img.hide();

        active = false;
    }

    $box.animate({right: pos[0]});
    $h2.animate({right: pos[1]}, show);

    $h2.data('toggleout', !$h2.data('toggleout'));

    function show() {
        !active || $img.show();
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KcF4u/4/

The goofy show/hide is hacked together. But it works...

Comment: You might also add `cursor: pointer;` to the `#news img` style definition, so you there's a pointer over it when you hover. Also, what's here isn't really written to accommodate multiple fly-outs. It would need to be refactored to handle more than one.

Comment: Here's a [bit of a reworking](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KcF4u/10/embedded/result/) ([source](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KcF4u/10/)) to try and accommodate multiple flyouts. I would strongly recommend you abandon the rotated text and just get images for those tabs; it'll look just as nice and won't make you go gray and bald early. For instance, IE9 doesn't display the rotated text correctly.

Comment: Thanks Jared that is very helpful, your right, that is a better workaround. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Mmm why don't you just hide it with .hide() on load and show it with .show() when you expand?

Comment: omg yes. I can't believe it. I tried it first and it didn't work, then realised I had forgot to put the "( )" at the end of "hide".

It is kind of working now though http://jsfiddle.net/KcF4u/3/ - do you know how I can delay the starting bit so the image does not pop up until expanded?